# Why the compiler is not compiling a line in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I was programming an application in C++ Builder 6, and I had encountered this rare problem:

```
void RotateDice()
{
  Graphics::TBitmap *MYbitmap = new Graphics::TBitmap();

  Randomize();
  int rn = random(6) + 1;

  switch (rn)
  {
    case 1:
    {
        //...
        break; 
    }
    //...  Some cases...
  }

  ShowDice();  //it's a function to show the dice
  delete MYbitmap;   //the compiler don't get it!!!!
}
```

In the line "ShowDice()", the compiler jumps to the final of the RotateDice() method, it doesn't "see" the line "delete MYbitmap". When I compile the program, every compiled line shows a little blue point in its left side, but that line don't show the blue point... it's like the compiler don't "see" the line of code. What's happening with that????

Note: Some days ago, I was writing a program in Delphi and I was advice of that problematic issue. Some like that happened to me in Delphi 7... So, waht the problem with that?

I am so sorry about my English. I am from Cuba.

Comment: Replace the line "delete MYbitmap" with cout << "something", run your program and check if you see that message in the console. If you see it then the problem is with the debugger, not the compiler, and you shouldn't worry too much. If you don't see the message then you should get a better compiler.

Comment: Please show the code in ShowDice.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: ShowDice() code is only like this: JvDice->Visible = true;

Compile with Optimizations??? what's that???

Answer (score 3):

Since the `ShowDice();` call doesn't depend on the `MYbitmap` variable, the compiler is free to re-order the last two statements. This might explain why you don't "hit" the line in the debugger. Disable **optimization** and try again.

Also, may I suggest using some [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) wrapper like [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr) or [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) instead of manual memory management?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood your problem, when you trace your application, the debugger "jumps over" the line `delete MYbitmap;`?

1. Try to put a breakpoint to this line. If it is not marked as such, we have strange IDE bug.

   ```
   ShowDice();
   delete MYbitmap;
   int a = 0; // try to add this dummy line and debug again
   ```
2. Maybe `ShowDice();` throws an exception? Then you'll never reach this line. Try to catch all exceptions and print the result. If it is the case, your code should similar to:

   ```
   try {
      ShowDice();
   }
   catch(...) {  // catch all exceptions and do something with them
      delete MYbitmap;
      throw;
   }
   delete MYbitmap;
   ```

Comment: In example 2, Mybitmap doesn't get deleted if ShowDice() doesn't throw.

Comment: No, no exceptions is possible in ShowDice();

Comment: Bill, thanks of comment. I have fixed that. Pitty, there is not standard for "finally".
MLB: How trick with "int a = 0" behaves? Also skips it?

Comment: There's no "finally" because what you're supposed to do is wrap the MYbitmap pointer in an object that deletes it on destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have optimization enabled when you compiled? Optimization has a way of making code that's very confusing to execute under a debugger. Try doing a full recompile with debugging information on and optimization completely disabled, just as a test.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
void RotateDice()
{
  Graphics::TBitmap MYbitmap;
  ...

  ShowDice();
  // No delete needed
};
```

Creating a TBitmap on the stack means that C++ is forced to delete it properly, even if ShowDice() throws an exception.

Does this work with C++ Builder 6?

Comment: No, TBitmap is a VCL class (which can't be created on the stack due to Delphi interoperability)

Comment: That looks like a declaration of a function named MYbitmap that takes void and returns a TBitmap.

Answer (score 0):

C++ Builder 6 compiler had a bug, rarely showing itself when you use these constructs:

1)

```
if(condition)
{
    <somecode>
    break;
}
```

2)

```
if(condition)
{
    <somecode>
    continue;
}
```

3)

```
if(condition)
{
    <somecode>
    goto label;
}
```

Here, "somecode" is going to be always skipped or always run with no regard to the result of the condition evaluation. The problem is solved when you remove "continue", "break" or "goto". It seems that the switch statement with a break could also have such "feature". 
Try to change the code before the glitched line this way:

```
if(rn == 1)
{
        //...
}
   //...  other cases...
else if(rn == ...)
{
   //... 
}
ShowDice();  //it's a function to show the dice
delete MYbitmap;   //works?
```

Comment: can you show a minimal complete code example that demos that bug you're talking about? I don't recall ever encountering this bug on CBuilder6.

Comment: @Victor T. unfortunately, I don't have such example. I encountered it a few times before at least bcb6 update4 and I couldn't reproduce it in a small sample. Assembler code showed that there was an unconditional jump over body of "if" right after condition evaluation. Nasty bug, it forced me to write in clear structured programming style for a while)